# php-fpm лимит по IP

Tags: php, centos

У меня сервер 
10x3ghz
рам 8гб
Centos 6.5, nginx, php-fpm, mysql

есть некий скрипт который долго выполняется, примерно 1 минут.
и когда я запускаю его, я не могу зайти на другие страницы сайта пока этот скрипт не выполнится. Я думал это nginx блокирует чтобы второго запроса не было пока первый не завершится. Но видел что страницы статические без проблем открываются. Наверное это лимит php-fpm. Но не могу как исправить. Я хочу чтобы разрешал 2 одновременных соединений

Скрипт запускаю через URL. 
Если в этот момент зайди на сайт с другого İP то все работает. В смысле ограничивается доступ только к ip который запускал скрипт.

```
[root@localhost ~]# grep ^pm.max_children /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
pm.max_children = 500
[root@localhost ~]# ps axu | grep -c fpm
132
```

Comment: Как скрипт запускаете? Через cli? Если да, то это дело не в fpm будет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел в чем проблема. Это файл сессии блокируется.

> Сессии, использующие файлы (по умолчанию в PHP), блокируют файл сессии сразу при открытии сессии функцией session_start() или косвенно при указании session.auto_start. После блокировки, ни один другой скрипт не может получить доступ к этому же файлу сессии, пока он не будет закрыт или при завершении скрипта или при вызове функции session_write_close().
>   Скорее всего это станет проблемой для сайтов, которые активно используют AJAX и делают несколько одновременных запросов. Простейшим путем решить эту проблему будет вызов функции session_write_close() сразу же как только все требуемые изменения в сессии будут сделаны, предпочтительно ближе к началу работы скрипта. Также можно использовать другой механизм сессии, который поддерживает конкурентный доступ.

Comment: Подскажите, а проблема решилась при использовании `session_write_close`?

Comment: Да. Проверено)  Все работает при session_write_close

Answer (score 0):

Сколько `fpm` процессов работают и сколько доступно можно проверить. Я писал об этом [здесь](http://jeka.by/ask/219/fpm-processes-count/).

Max кол-во fpm-процессов ищем в конфиге fpm:

```
grep ^pm.max_children /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

Количество fpm, которые задействованы на сервере:

```
pgrep fpm | wc -l
```

Если скрипт запускаете через `cli` (или даже не важно как), а fpm в это время перестаёт отвечать, то скорее всего скрипт вызывает лок таблиц, *в которые читает/пишет fpm*. Если одновременных клиентов много, то по сути fpm будут ждать, а в итоге  limit их количества закончится и nginx будет отдавать скорее всего 502 bad gateway.

limit по ip нет на уровне php-fpm...

Проверяли ли вы, открывается ли с другого ip сайт во время работы скрипта?

Посмотрите еще какие ошибки в логах есть.

Comment: я в первую очередь проверил с другого İP, сайт работал нормально. Поэтому странно стало. Когда захожу с того же İP который запускал тяжелый скрипт, выдает 404 ошибку после долгой загрузки, но с другого ip все работает.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# grep ^pm.max_children /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf
pm.max_children = 500
[root@localhost ~]# ps axu | grep -c fpm
132
[root@localhost ~]#

Comment: @FəqanÇələbizadə свободных fpm предостаточно... а сам скрипт внутри себя не может по ip или по совокупности параметров какие то действия (локи) делать? а curl-запросы в это время тоже 404 отдают?

Comment: В скрипте используется множества file_get_contents(локальный файл), разбираю на части и добавляю на базу данных. Кажется это mysql. Блокировка таблиц мускл логично, но блокировка по IP возможно вообще?

Comment: curl через SSH работает

Comment: нашел) это из-за session_start() . создал php с кодом <?php 

session_start();
sleep(10);

?> опять тоже самое получилось. убрал session_start() все сработало. Интересно как это исправить?)